# OpenGL (ANGLE) + XAML (UWP)

Tags: uwp, opengl-es, uwp-xaml, c++-cx, egl

I'm trying to get OpenGL code running on UWP XAML application.
I found some information regarding this, but seems there's nothing like complete walkthrough.
I'm completele beginner in UPW, XAML and EGL, so I managed to create following code from various tutorials:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <EGL/egl.h>
#include <GLES/gl.h>
#include <angle_windowsstore.h>

using namespace Windows::UI::Core;
using namespace Windows::UI::Xaml;
using namespace Windows::UI::Xaml::Controls;
using namespace Platform;
using Windows::ApplicationModel::SuspendingEventArgs;
using Windows::ApplicationModel::Activation::LaunchActivatedEventArgs;
using Windows::Foundation::Collections::PropertySet;
using Windows::Foundation::EventHandler;

static EGLint const openGlAttributes[] = {
    EGL_RED_SIZE, 1,
    EGL_GREEN_SIZE, 1,
    EGL_BLUE_SIZE, 1,
    EGL_NONE
};

ref class MyApp sealed : Application {
private:
    SwapChainPanel^ swapChainPanel;
    CoreWindow^ coreWindow;
    EGLDisplay display;
    EGLSurface surface;
    bool stopped;

public:
    MyApp() {
        stopped = false;
    }

    virtual void OnLaunched(LaunchActivatedEventArgs^ e) override {
        auto canvas = ref new Canvas();

        auto swapChainPanel = ref new SwapChainPanel();
        swapChainPanel->Width = 800;
        swapChainPanel->Width = 600;
        canvas->Children->Append(swapChainPanel);
        canvas->SetLeft(swapChainPanel, 0);
        canvas->SetTop(swapChainPanel, 0);


        Window::Current->Content = canvas;
        Window::Current->Activate();

        coreWindow = Window::Current->CoreWindow;
        InitGL(Window::Current);

        WeakReference selfRef(this);
        Suspending += ref new SuspendingEventHandler([selfRef](Object^ sender, SuspendingEventArgs^ args) {
            auto self = selfRef.Resolve<MyApp>();
            self->stopped = true;
        });
        Resuming += ref new EventHandler<Object^>([selfRef](Object^ sender, Object^ args) {
            auto self = selfRef.Resolve<MyApp>();
            self->stopped = false;
        });

        ScheduleRendering();
    }

private:

    void InitGL(Window^ window) {
        display = eglGetDisplay(EGL_DEFAULT_DISPLAY);
        eglInitialize(display, NULL, NULL);

        EGLConfig config;
        EGLint numConfig;
        eglChooseConfig(display, openGlAttributes, &config, 1, &numConfig);

        auto surfaceCreationProperties = ref new PropertySet();
        surfaceCreationProperties->Insert(ref new String(EGLNativeWindowTypeProperty), swapChainPanel);

        auto context = eglCreateContext(display, config, EGL_NO_CONTEXT, NULL);
        surface = eglCreateWindowSurface(display, config, reinterpret_cast<EGLNativeWindowType>(surfaceCreationProperties), NULL);
        eglMakeCurrent(display, surface, surface, context);
    }

    void RenderScene() {
        glClearColor(1.0, 0, 0, 1.0);
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        glFlush();

        eglSwapBuffers(display, surface);

        ScheduleRendering();
    }

    void ScheduleRendering() {
        if (stopped) {
            return;
        }
        WeakReference selfRef(this);
        coreWindow->Dispatcher->RunIdleAsync(ref new IdleDispatchedHandler([selfRef](IdleDispatchedHandlerArgs^ args) {
            auto self = selfRef.Resolve<MyApp>();
            self->RenderScene();
        }));
    }
};

int main(Array<String^>^ args) {
    Application::Start(ref new ApplicationInitializationCallback([](ApplicationInitializationCallbackParams^ p) {
        ref new MyApp();
    }));
    return 0;
}
```

However, it simply does not work.
At least this code does not crash.
Next, I examined InitGL in debugger and all calls to EGL complete normally.

There are several things I'm not sure of:

1. Should I intialize SwapChainPanel accoring [this guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows/uwp/gaming/directx-and-xaml-interop#swapchainpanel-and-gaming), or ANGLE does this for me?
2. Should I perform rendering in idle, or there's something like Paint event?

Comment: I created a Blank app with C++ in VS2019 and installed the "ANGLE.WindowsStore" from NuGet,but still couldn't include **"<GLES/gl.h>"**.Can you show me what steps you took to help me reproduce it?

Comment: I did not create project from VS. Instead, I wrote CMakeLists.txt and generated sln file from it. I included ANGLE dependency from vcpkg.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like I was wrong when I wrote that everything initializes properly.
This call returned `EGL_NO_SOURCE`:

```c
eglMakeCurrent(display, surface, surface, context);
```

I suppose it's because of we have to wait when `SwapChainPanel` gets initiliazed, so when I called `eglMakeCurrent` from `Load` event of `swapChainPanel`, everything started to work.
Also, there are several things that aren't obvious, like `swapChainPanel` may loose GL context unexpectedly and thus you have to recreate it when something goes wrong.
I found [this template](https://github.com/microsoft/angle/tree/c61d0488abd9663e0d4d2450db7345baa2c0dfb6/templates/10/Windows/Universal/XamlUniversal) in Microsoft fork of ANGLE and used it as the source of inspiration.